# Why does Rails runs an additional unnecessary query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following Rails Code, in which it technically do two queries max, but for some reason, the console shows three different queries as shown in the screenshot below. My question is why does it run the `SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"` query for when it's not necessary?

**Query**

```
    page = Page.includes(:page_roles)
    page.where(is_deleted: false).index_by(&:name)
    page_results = {}
    page.each do |entry|
        result_entry = entry.as_json;
        result_entry['page_roles'] = entry.page_roles
        page_results[entry.name] = result_entry
    end
```

**Console Output**

```
Page Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages" WHERE "pages"."is_deleted" = $1  [["is_deleted", false]]
PageRole Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "page_roles".* FROM "page_roles" WHERE "page_roles"."page_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
Page Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "pages".* FROM "pages"
CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "page_roles".* FROM "page_roles" WHERE "page_roles"."page_id" IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
Completed 200 OK in 117ms (Views: 16.9ms | ActiveRecord: 17.0ms)
```

[image: Screenshot of the console]

Comment: Please type in the code from the console, it's unreadable.

Comment: Sorry about that, updated the question

Comment: it's actually 4 queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's why:

```
page = Page.includes(:page_roles)
page.where(is_deleted: false).index_by(&:name) # your first two queries (pages + page_roles). 
                                               # query is triggered by index_by (method of enumerable, not activerecord) and result is ignored
                                               # as it's not saved anywhere.

page_results = {}
page.each do |entry| # your second two queries. Note that this one doesn't use `is_deleted: false` filter.
                     # page_roles query is served from cache as it didn't change.
    result_entry = entry.as_json;
    result_entry['page_roles'] = entry.page_roles
    page_results[entry.name] = result_entry
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't the `page` still have the previously attached methods? For example, when doing `page.each`, wouldn't the `page` variable still contain the previously attached methods `page.includes(:page_roles)` and `page.where(is_deleted: false).index_by(&:name)`?

Comment: `includes` - yes (because it's saved to `pages`). The other one - no.

Answer (score 1):

that's because the first assignment. You can short all of that by doing:

```
page_results = 
  Page
    .includes(:page_roles)
    .where(is_deleted: false)
    .group_by(&:name)
```

Comment: I did it that way because, if not tried to access the `page_roles` attribute from the resulting entries, then that attribute will be left unset.

Comment: I see the problem, you can use a serializer then https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/master/docs/general/getting_started.md

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you've got the `page.where` query which will still use the ActiveRecord query interface on the Page table and not use the ActiveRecord collection stored as `page`.